# What is the shorter verb for "establishing a many-to-many relationship"?

Tags: many-to-many, terminology, relationships, relational-algebra

When we establish a one-to-one or many-to-one relationship, we can call it mapping. For example, we *map* a spouse to his/her spouse or each child to its parent. But what would be the verb singifying an establishment of a many-to-many relationship, underlining that it is not a 1+ to 1 relationship?

Comment: 'Mapping' is still relevant in my opinion, regardless of whether it's 1 to 1, 1 to many, many to 1 or many to many.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Yes, it is, but the purpose is to distinguish between x-to-one and many-to-many

Comment: It's an interesting question but I'm not convinced you can to be honest. Just for laughs, you should post this on [english.stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/) and watch them fall over themselves to invent a new word. :D Maybe such a verb exists after all.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I had the same idea initially : ) It is sometimes funny how trying to grok math terms leads you to combing through dicionaries for the definitions of the most basic words like "assoiciate".

Comment: Mate, I have exactly the same problem trying to convert code into a user manual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can **distribute**, **permute**, or **combine** multiple groups to define many to many relationships. Mapping a group to other groups does not explicitly state if the members are crossed or not, like in a Cartesian product.

Permute is a more specific case because the order matters, but both permutations and combinations are the result of distributing a set among other sets (or groups among other groups).

Comment: Thanks, this is very insighful. But could you provide any reference on "you can distribute, permute, or combine multiple groups to define many to many relationships"? That is, that there are exactly three distinct ways to do so? I'd like to learn more on the topic, it feels that I'm missing something simple yet important.

Comment: Specifically, I've never seen a term "distribution" used in this context, and [Wikipedia: Distribution (math)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution) doesn't seem to be relevant here. Permutations and combinations are more clear in this context, though their relation to many-to-many relationships is a new idea for me, thanks for that as well.

Comment: anything defined by a function is technically a distribution, and you can describe this 'handing out' of groups to groups with a generating function. Distribute is vague but is useful in a general case where order may or may not matter yet.

Answer (score 1):

To cross reference or to associate. I do not know if there is a definitive term but these seem plausible.

Comment: Both are nice, though dictionary says "associate" is just "connect in one's mind", which could be 1+ to 1 as well.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions use of HasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) as a term in ROR and Cakephp also